# How to fix HTTP Post Json 410 Error using Make.com?

Tags: json, http, post, make.com

I'm trying to send data to Koala Writer AI via Make but can't seem to make it work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCNz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Z2H.png)

In the API key section, I put "Bearer token"

and then for the request content, I followed exactly what was in the Koala AI Api docs: https://koala.sh/pages/api-docs

```
fetch("https://koala.sh/api/articles/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "bearer 96cef1fc-c041-496b-baf4-b6e8a5b620ca",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    targetKeyword: "can you eat watermelon seeds?",
    gptVersion: "gpt-3.5",
  }),
});
```

However I keep getting a 401 error. How do I fix this?

I followed exactly what was on the API doc

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting a 401 error, it's likely that the issue is the API key. Since you are using the HTTP module to make the request, you can input the API key in the HTTP modules 'Headers" drop down menu. [image: HTTP Module Example]